# C# Linq using distinct with union

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table in db as :

```
Id Name   Stream  Version   UId  Tab    Key    Value  CreatedOn   CreatedBy
1  Name1   GOP      1       U1   Tab1   co      1     07/01/2018  S, Adam
2  Name1   GOP      1       U2   Tab1   co      1     07/03/2018  S, Adam
3  Name1   GOP      1       U3   Tab2   st      2     07/03/2018  S, Adam
4  Name1   GOP      2       OR   Tab1   co      1     07/02/2018  P, Silver
5  Name2   GOP      1       OR   Tab1   co      1     07/02/2018  P, Silver
6  Name3   GOP      0       OR1  Tab0   coe     1     07/02/2018  S, Adam
7  Name3   GOP      0       OR2  Tab1   coe     1     07/02/2018  S, Adam
8  Name2   LNT      3       NE   Tab1   st      4     07/01/2018  P, Silver
9  Name2   LNT      3       NE1  Tab1   co      2     07/01/2018  P, Silver
10 Name2   LNT      2       NE2  Tab1   st      3     07/01/2018  P, Silver
11 Name2   LNT      0       NE   Tab9   co      5     07/01/2018  R, Henry
12 Name3   TTE      0       TT   Tab1   ee      2     07/02/2018  R. Henry
13 Name3   TTE      0       T1   Tab1   ee      2     07/02/2018  R. Henry
```

I want to write a query that would give me the highest version of set together with distinct version 0.

For this I wrote the query as but this does not get my desired output:

```
var data = response.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Stream })
           .SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(row => row.Version).Take(1)) //This gives highest version 
           .Union(response.Where(x => int.Parse(x.Version) == 0)) // This gives version 0
           .OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedOn).ToList();
```

Desired Output On UI

```
Id Name   Stream  Version   CreatedOn   CreatedBy                         
4  Name1   GOP      2       07/02/2018  P, Silver   //This is shown as 2 is the highest version for Name1 & GOP combination
5  Name2   GOP      1       07/02/2018  P, Silver   //This is shown as Name & Stream combination is different 
6  Name1   GOP      0       07/02/2018  S, Adam     //Version 0 is always shown - Combination of Name & Stream may or may not have more than one 0 version
8  Name2   LNT      3       07/01/2018  P, Silver   //This is shown as 3 is the highest version for Name2 & LNT combination
11 Name2   LNT      0       07/01/2018  R, Henry    //Version 0 is always shown 
12 Name3   TTE      0       07/02/2018  R, Henry    //Version 0 is always shown
```

On the UI I am trying to just show the trimmed down version of a set. When the user clicks on that set I would then show details for all the individual sets within the set.

Right now I only struck with how to update my query so I can get my desired result.

----Updated---

Right now what I got working is individual lists:

```
 var data1 = response.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Stream})
              .SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(row => row.Version).Take(1))
              .Where(x => int.Parse(x.Version) != 0)
              .OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedOn).ToList();
```

The above gives me all latest versions for a given name and stream.

```
var data2 = response.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Stream})
             .Select(g => g.First())
             .Where(x => int.Parse(x.Version) == 0)
             .OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedOn).ToList();
```

The above gives me all 0 versions for a given name and stream.

I think these individual lists works fine at the moment, but how to merge them.

Is there a way to join/merge these lists together so as to return just a single set. Or if there is a way to merge these 2 linq queries together.

---Updated-----

```
    var set1 = response.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Stream})
                .SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(row => row.Version).Take(1))
               .Where(x => int.Parse(x.Version) != 0).ToList();

    var set2 = response.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Stream, x.Version})
                       .Select(g => g.First())
                       .Where(x => int.Parse(x.Version) == 0).ToList();

    var setmerged = set1.Union(set2).OrderByDescending(o => o.CreatedOn).ToList();
```

Got it working by above not sure if this is an clean solution.

Comment: Maybe also like the line above: `.Union(response.Where(x => int.Parse(x.Version) == 0).Take(1))`?

Comment: No, with this I don't get the 0 version at all. The result is just the version 2.

Comment: I can't reproduce your test. With `.Take( 1 )` I get the results you want.

Comment: Why don't you just make 2 queries?

Comment: @johnny5 you mean create 2 separate linq queries, first with selectmany as above and second with union. How do I join these 2 then?

Comment: the query returns exactly what it should, you take 1 item for version 1 and then add 2 for version 0, result consists of 3 items

Comment: @derloopkat sorry I dint understand you. SelectMany together with Take(1) returns me highest version which works fine. Since I also want version 0 I did union but now I get duplicate of version0 which I am trying to remove. So basically one can have multiple sets but just on the UI to display I want one set of that version

Comment: How are you supposed to decide _which_ Version 0 row to include? Why did you include `Id` 3 and not 4?

Comment: @NetMage I have updated my query to show more detailed explanation

Comment: @user1563677 Your updated solution is quite fine now. But DO NOT use ToList() in the first two sets. It will execute the command already on the actual database and therefore the UNION operation would be processed by your program. Only use it in the setmerged line.

Comment: Note that `Union` makes sure there are no duplicates, but you already know that from your queries, so you should use `Concat` instead. Why did you use `SelectMany`/`Take(1)` in your first query instead of `Select`/`First` like your second query? You know each group contains at least one member.

Answer (score 0):

**Wrong use of DISTINCT**

This doesn't make sense. `DISTINCT` is used to filter duplicate rows, which they aren't as only the version number is the same. Where should the DBS know from, which `CreatedOn` value it should use?

**Better solution**

What you want is to use `GROUP BY` in order to group everything with the same version value. Be aware that you'll need to use an aggregate function like `MAX()`on the other columns in order to use it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So from the looks of your updated question, you want the top one of each distinct version, name and stream.

According to the dataset you've provided, and the result sets you want, there is no need to do anything special for the 0 version because the conditions for grabbing the distinct version should include the 0 version as well.

You haven't really specified what the order of the version should be so for now I'll assume that the one that was most recently updated is the one you want

```
response.GroupBy(x => new { x.Name, x.Stream, x.Version })
        .SelectMany(g => g.OrderByDescending(row => row.CreatedOn).Take(1))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Trivial question, OrderByAscending is not found?

Comment: My fault that was pseudo code I've update, you just need to use orderby

Comment: @user1563677 Let me know, that should resolve your issue

Comment: dont know if the query works, there are some errors in the way its constructed. I would check it later in the day and let you know.

Comment: I have updated my query to show more detailed explanation of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: what I ended up doing for now was to create 2 individual lists, one for getting the latest version and one for getting versions 0 and then using union to join these 2.   See my updated post.  Not sure if this is the right approach to join or if this can be done in a single statement of linq.

Comment: @user1563677, from your post it looks like you needed the latest of each version, and the 0,  Which is redudant, because if you get the latest of each version it will also include the 0.  This code get the latest of each version which will include the 0 version as well

Comment: @user1563677 Your updated solution will not get the desired output you've provided in the question, your updated solution will only get the 3 and all of the 0 record

Comment: let me evaluate that, will get back to you